# how to use element's of a page in other page in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my `MainWindow.xaml` is a data grid view and i x:name it "MyList".

> System.InvalidOperationException: ''MyList' name cannot be found in
>   the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'.'

Guide me how i name my data grid to able to access it in other pages or how i reference or scope MainWindow.xaml to other pages / usercontrols

Edit:

this is my data grid Named MyList and it is in MainWindow : ```

````
                                              VerticalGridLinesBrush="White" 
                                              BorderThickness="1" 
                                              CanUserResizeColumns="False" 
                                              CanUserResizeRows="False" 
                                              ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"
                                              AllowDrop="True"
                                              SelectionMode="Extended"   
                                              Foreground="#FF434343"
                                              AlternatingRowBackground="#FFEFF0DD"
                                               CanUserAddRows="False" Background="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                                              >
                                        <DataGrid.RenderTransform>
                                            <TransformGroup>
                                                <ScaleTransform/>
                                                <SkewTransform/>
                                                <RotateTransform/>
                                                <TranslateTransform/>
                                            </TransformGroup>
                                        </DataGrid.RenderTransform>

                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ردیف" Width="75" FontSize="16" Binding="{Binding Path=id}" IsReadOnly="True" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="نام" Width="200"  FontSize="16" Binding="{Binding Path=name}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="تعداد" Width="auto" FontSize="16" Binding="{Binding Path=tedad}" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>```
````

now here is app.xaml and i need to reference mainwindow to here but i dont know how t add it in xaml :```

```
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
```

```
    <!--#region User Control Add-->
    <!--#region Anime Open Add-->
    <Storyboard x:Key="anmOpenAdd">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="AddPage">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-350"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="-350"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="-320"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Anime Close Add-->
    <Storyboard x:Key="anmCloseAdd">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="AddPage">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"   Value="-320"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-350"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="20"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Edit User Control-->

    <!--#region Edit Open Up-->
    <Storyboard x:Key="anmEditOpen">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="EditPage">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-320"/>

            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="anmMyListEditOpen">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="MyList">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="320"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <!--#endregion-->


    <!--#region Edit Close Up-->
    <Storyboard x:Key="anmEditClose">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="EditPage">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"  Value="0"/>

            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3"  Value="-340"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="anmMyListEditClose">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="{Binding ElementName=MyList}">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="320"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3"  Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Resource Disctionary-->
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.Grey.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <!--#endregion-->

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: You need a reference to a an instance of the `MainWindow` to be able to access any of its members to begin with.

Comment: tell me how i can reference  an instance of mainwindow in App.xaml

Comment: how i can scope mainwindow to other pages

Comment: The other page needs a reference to the `MainWindow`. If there is no window, there is no "MyList". Tell us how you setup and display your pages. How are they connected to the window?

Comment: see!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: Why do you need to reference it?

Comment: what else i can do? 

i need to reference it to app.xaml cause im gonna animate it in there>
and data grid is in MainWindow 
some one tell me how

Comment: I think this is not the right way of doing it. You should use triggers e.g `DataTrigger` or `EventTrigger` to trigger an animation. If the `DataGrid` is a child of `MainWindow` then only `MainWindow` should be responsible to animate its children. What _exactly_ are you trying to do?